# Unity 2d URP Project, can't edit Forward Renderer asset

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, urp

I Have to make Stencil Shader in Unity URP 2D project, and I found that I have to use URP Forward Renderer.asset to make Stencil Shader.

But In my Project, I couldn't edit Forward Renderer Asset.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prbL7.png)

so What should I Do for edit Forward Renderer asset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a URP 2D Asset in your project. Never try to edit anything in the Packages folder.

[image: Create -> Renderib -> URP 2D Renderer]